# Is there an equivalent of ${LIB} for dyld?

Tags: trace, dyld, ld-preload

I'm working on a Mac launcher for a trace library - the tracing works by adding the library to `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` (the Mac equivalent of `LD_PRELOAD`). The `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` variable is then propagated by the trace library as further processes are spawned.

The trouble is that I need the 32-bit version of the trace library to be used for 32-bit tracee processes and the 64-bit version for 64-bit tracee processes. In the Linux launcher I have, this is achieved by using `${LIB}` in `LD_PRELOAD` - the dynamic loader (`ld.so`) then replaces this with "the right thing" when loading a process.

Is there an equivalent of `ld.so`'s `${LIB}` variable for `dyld` on Mac? I couldn't immediately see one when I looked through the man page (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html), but I may just be reading it wrong. If not, is there another way of achieving the same effect please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to compile your inserted library as a fat binary (e.g., multiple architectures in the same binary). This should allow a single value of `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` to work for subprocesses of various architectures.